# C# XMLのノードを読み込んだ時IdだけがNullになってしまう

Tags: c#, xml

XMLのUsersノード内をforeachしてIdとKeyとAddressを読み込むようにしたいのですが、IdだけNullになってしまい読み込めません。
どうしたらIdも読めるようにできるのかご教示いただけたらと思います
Idが読めない以外は一応動いてるのですが、独学で悪戦苦闘しながら組んでるので、おかしな部分もあるかもしれません。
ダメ出しやアドバイスをよろしくお願いいたします。

```
<AppSettings>
  <FileFolder>C:\</FileFolder>
  <SKey>0</SKey>
  <Users>
    <User Id="User0001">
      <Key></Key>
      <Address>D:\C#作成物\顔マーク_フリー素材\img038.png</Address>
    </User>
    <User Id="User0002">
      <Key>２</Key>
      <Address />
    </User>
    <User Id="User0003">
      <Key>３</Key>
      <Address />
    </User>
  </Users>
</AppSettings>
```

```
[Serializable()]
public class AppSettings
{
    public string FileFolder { get; set; }
    public byte SKey { get; set; }  // ラベルの配列番号
    // ユーザ情報
    public List<User> Users { get; set; }
    public class User
    {
        public string Id { get; set; } // ID
        public string Key { get; set; } // ユーザ名
        public string Address { get; set; } // ユーザ画像アドレス
    }

    //Settingsクラスのインスタンス
    [NonSerialized()]
    private static AppSettings _instance;
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnore]
    public static AppSettings Instance
    {
        get
        {
            //_instanceがnullのときは、新しくインスタンスを作成する
            if (_instance == null)
                _instance = new AppSettings();

            return _instance;
        }
        set { _instance = value; }
    }
}

private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //--中略--
    foreach (AppSettings.User userLabel in AppSettings.Instance.Users) //保存ユーザラベルの読込
    {
        if (userLabel.Key != "")
        { 
            UserList.Items.Add(userLabel.Key);
            if (UCount == KeyNum) UserName.Text = userLabel.Key; //保存されてるUserIdのKey
        }
        else
        {
            UserList.Items.Add(userLabel.Id);
            if (UCount == KeyNum)
            {
                UserName.Text = userLabel.Id;
                UserPicture.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(userLabel.Address); //保存されてるUserIdのAddress
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: この記事が参考になるのでは？ [C# 属性とテキストで構成されるXMLタグをデシリアライズする為のクラス設計](https://zero-config.com/dotnet/xmlserializer001.html)

Comment: kunifさん、ありがとうございます。
 public string Id { get; set; } // ID
にXMLエレメント(タグ)の属性(Attribute)を入れてあげなきゃいけなかったんですね。
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute("Id")]
を追加してあげたら、ちゃんと認識してくれました。
素早い回答助かりました。ありがとうございました。

Comment: 登録の完了を押したらコメント追加とか出来なくなりました。
質問者なのですが、kunifさんの参考リンクで解決しまいたので、この回答をもって完了したいと思います（やり方が分かりません……）
ありがとうございました

Comment: アカウントを 2 つ作成してしまった場合は、[お問い合わせ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/contact)をすることで、 2 つのアカウントをマージ出来ます。アカウントをマージするための手順は[こちら](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)に記載されているので、差し支えがなければ、一度お試しください。

Answer (score 1):

この記事が参考になるのでは？ [C# 属性とテキストで構成されるXMLタグをデシリアライズする為のクラス設計](https://zero-config.com/dotnet/xmlserializer001.html)

```
public class User
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute("Id")] // XMLエレメント(タグ)の属性(Attribute)を入れる
    public string Id { get; set; } // ID
    public string Key { get; set; } // ユーザ名
    public string Address { get; set; } // ユーザ画像アドレス
}
```

---

<sup>この投稿は @kunif さんの[コメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/59628/#comment64315_59628)などを元に編集し、[コミュニティWiki](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1583)として投稿しました。</sup>